# Change syntax of JS file so it can be `required()` into another file with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

First time I am using `webpack` on Laravel 5.4 and playing around to learn.

I have this `teal.js` file which came from this [3d dice example](http://a.teall.info/dice/).

```
"use strict";

window.teal = {};
window.$t = window.teal;

teal.copyto = function(obj, res) {
    if (obj == null || typeof obj !== 'object') return obj;
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        for (var i = obj.length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            res[i] = $t.copy(obj[i]);
    }
    else {
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
                res[i] = $t.copy(obj[i]);
        }
    }
    return res;
};

teal.copy = function(obj) {
    if (!obj) return obj;
    return teal.copyto(obj, new obj.constructor());
};

teal.element = function(name, props, place) {
    var dom = document.createElement(name);
    if (props) for (var i in props) dom.setAttribute(i, props[i]);
    if (place) place.appendChild(dom);
    return dom;
};
.... MANY MORE
```

I want to be able to include it into my `js bootstrap` file.

```
window.teal = require(./dice/teal);
```

This is not working. First time with `webpack` coming from `gulp` where files are just concatenated, I am learning all about scopes and `webpack`.

What is missing in terms of syntax so I can require `teal.js`?

The `js bootstrap` code is:

```
window.teal = require('./dice/teal');             <-- problem
window.CANNON = require('./dice/cannon.min');     <-- ok
window.THREE = require('./dice/three.min');       <-- ok
window.dice = require('./dice/dice');             <-- ok
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it to work, without it beeing refactored, you could try something dirty like this:

Below `"use strict"` remove:

```
window.teal = {};
window.$t = window.teal;
```

and add:

```
let teal = {}
```

Finally, at the end of the file add:

```
module.exports = window.teal
```

This is the fastest solution I could think of.
This way you get rid of the non existent window object, depending on your environment, and expose all the functions assigned to the `teal` object to your module exports.

Maybe I missed something about the structure of your file, tell me if its not working.